# How many Daleks are left?

Tags: doctor-who

The Skittles breed of Dalek were pretty limited in number. One by one we've seen a couple meet their end, if memory serves.

Which Power Ranger Daleks are still* kicking about the Universe?

---

<sup>* Well, OK; "still" is a fluid concept. We jump around in space and time, and so do the Daleks, so we could say that — depending when we materialise — they're all alive, all the time (which, incidentally, is something that *really* bothers me about the Doctor deciding to fake his death). But we the viewers still magically seem to have a linear, progressing view .. so let's think in terms of televised adventures. :)</sup>

[image]

Comment: It would help if you made it clear what you mean by "Skittles breed" and "Power Ranger Daleks."  I saw one episode of the Power Rangers early on and avoided the show like the plague from then on, so I'm not clear just what you mean.

Comment: You've hit on the fundamental un-answer-ability baked into the question. The only 'rule' about Dr Who time travel is that bad things happen when you interfere with established events. The Doctor can fake his death because no one can be really sure which incarnations of him are ahead or behind on his own timescale.

The Daleks have multiple locations in time and space where they can be revived from. Typically they are also not destroyed in altercations with the Doctor. And finally, they can reproduce. It would be impossible or nearly so to truly eliminate them.

Comment: @TangoOversway The "Skittles" and "Power Rangers" comments most likely refer to the new "Pure" Daleks from the episode [Victory of the Daleks](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1577258/).  The new "Pure" Daleks come in a variety of colors, instead of the uniform grey or grey and gold Daleks of the past.  The comments in [this answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/4576/1359) describe the colors of the new Daleks.

Comment: @DampeS8N: ... which is why I said "in terms of televised adventures". Linearly, in airing order, X pure Daleks were created and Y have since been killed. How many? (This is also why my original title is fine; in air order, all previous varieties of Dalek are already deceased.)

Comment: The real question is, How many do the plot require?  Also, are Daleks, genetically speaking, able to taste the rainbow?

Comment: There's always at least one more than the Doctor believes are left...

Comment: Oddly enough, the nickname my friends and I settled on was "Mighty Morphin' Power Daleks," though I maintain they look like Tupperware.

Comment: See any bodies? Then there are always enough. We have the Skittles brand still missing, no idea how many of the Dalak Parliament are left, we have some from the parallel universe still out there SOMEWHERE/WHEN. Really, there are always enough Dalaks caught between the splinters of time to always have one when Dr. Who needs its infusion of nostalgia, camp and old fashion plunger-based terror. REPOPULATE!

Comment: +1 for Skittles & Power Rangers. I'll never see them the same again!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I count it thus:

- All the Daleks were thought destroyed in the Time War.
- Since then, one crashed on Earth in 1962 and was found in 2012 in Henry Van Statten's collection; that killed itself.
- The Dalek Emperor's ship also turned out to have survived, and he created an army out of harvested humans, but Bad Wolf!Rose destroyed all that.
- Then the Cult of Skaro escaped the void and turned up with the Genesis Ark, but the Ark and all the Daleks in it were sucked back into the void.
- The Cult of Skaro (now the only surviving Daleks in the universe) escaped via temporal shift and made it to 1930 Manhattan.
- Daleks Sec, Thay and Jast all got killed, Dalek Caan escaped and shifted back into the Time War, where he saved Davros and escaped.
- They built a Dalek army out of Davros' cells. Both Davros and Caan presumably died when the Crucible was destroyed, so did almost the whole army.
- As always "one ship survived" and ends up in 1941.
- The Ironside!Daleks use the Doctor to reactivate the Progenitor and are promptly killed by the Power-Ranger-Daleks.
- That left the New Paradigm Daleks the only remaining ones.

  As I recall, there were five of those (that we were shown).

  - One was turned to stone in The Big Bang and killed by River shortly after, though that might have been undone by the rebooting of the universe.
  - One was incapacitated (and presumably killed) by the Doctor at the beginning of "The Wedding of River Song".

**So in short there are three, possibly four, Daleks left by my count.**

Comment: Nice accounting of the modern age appearances.

Comment: REPOPULATE! Ew, the images of Dalak procreation came to me and I am in need of Brain Bleach (tm) to erase those images.

Comment: Sadly now there appear to be a million of all kinds of the dang things. Silly show.

Answer (score 4):

Unknown.  The last time we saw them was in the S5 2-part finale.  They were part of the alliance that created the Pandorica and entrapped the Doctor.  When the universe ended, they were destroyed along with all the rest of the aliens in the Underhenge.  One was resurrected, then killed by River.  So at that point, all of them should have been destroyed.

However, when the universe was rebooted, presumably that means all the enemies we saw die/cease to exist ended up also rebooted.  So they're possibly still alive out there, somewhere, somewhen.

Comment: You just raised an interesting question the writers may have overlooked.

Comment: Indeed, especially since one was seen apparently recently-hurt in The Wedding Of River Song

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal I thought we only saw its eye-stalk.

Comment: @Keen: And its broken body whilst the Doctor had a conversation with it.

Comment: we have seen that the Daleks are capable of making new, and even "better", Daleks as need demands, so I assume that like roaches, if you see one, there are tons more.

Comment: _Asylum of the Daleks_ threw all of this out of the water. :(

Answer (score -1):

In Doctor Who Resolution the thirteenth doctor episode there was a reconnaissance scout dalek which faced the female doctor and the dalek died.

Also even though its Wikipedia, this Wikipedia page has a good list of several types of daleks to trigger any memories anyone has that may add more to the discussion

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalek_variants

Comment: Recon scout daleks supposedly *predate* most other kinds of dalek including the skittles brand version.

Comment: Yes but their may be other recon scout daleks who had survived the time war other then those mentioned in the episode kind of like how the daleks in that tenth doctor episode came out of the bubble that lies outside of time in the episode where the daleks fought the cybermen

Comment: OP was wanting to know about the new coloured daleks, not just daleks *in general*